# Parsley + Rails 5 + Unable to validate Email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, parsley.js

Model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  validates :email,
        presence: true,
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

HTML :

```
<%=
   f.email_field :email,
   placeholder: 'email',
   class: "form-control",
   id:"user_email",
   data: {
     parsley_required: "",
     parsley_pattern: User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX,
     parsley_type: "email"
   }
%>
```

After Compile :

```
<input placeholder="email" class="form-control" id="user_email" data-parsley-required="" data-parsley-pattern="&quot;(?i-mx:\\A([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})\\z)&quot;" data-parsley-type="email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]">
```

Not working. Please suggest

Comment: JS RegExp does not support inline modifiers and `\A` / `\z` anchors. The `data-parsley-pattern` should be set to `"^[^@\s]+@(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$"`.

Comment: Replaced User constant with your suggested value. Got ERROR
activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:44:in `check_options_validity': A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with (ArgumentError)

Comment: See a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tnevy0f/1/).

Comment: I want to set regex as constant in Rails application

Comment: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /^[^@\s]+@(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/
Okay, means it has to be some different format

Comment: What if you do it like `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = '[^@\s]+@(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}'`, and then `format: { with: Regexp.new("\\A#{VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}\\z") }` and `parsley_pattern: "^"+User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX + "$",`?

Comment: Does it work like that? Let me know if I should post that with explanations.

Comment: Yes, Please it is working as you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143844/discussion-between-rubyist-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start of string anchor in Ruby is defined with `\A` operator and end of string anchor is expressed with `\z`. However, in JavaScript, `^` and `$` anchors are used respectively. Moreover, when you send the Ruby `Regexp` object to the JS Parsley, the `#to_s` is run on it and you get the pattern mixed with modifiers that are added in their *inline* form, e.g. `(?-im:)`.

What you can do is set the value of `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX` to a *String* like  `'[^@\s]+@(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}'` (note I removed unnecessary capturing groups as you are not going to access those submatches, and also not the backslash is single because the literal is a single quoted one), and then build the regex dynamically on the RoR part with `format: { with: Regexp.new("\\A#{VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}\\z") }` (so, the anchors are correct for Ruby - the backslashes are doubled since it is a double quoted string literal) and pass the `^`/`$` anchors to Parsley JS with `parsley_pattern: "^"+User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX + "$"`.

```
Resulting model:

class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = '[^@\s]+@(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}'
  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    format: { with: Regexp.new("\\A#{VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}\\z") }
end
```

And the resulting HTML:

```
<%=
    f.email_field :email,
    placeholder: 'email',
    id:"user_email",
    data: {
      parsley_required: "",
      parsley_pattern: "^"+User::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX + "$",
      parsley_type: "email"
    }
%>
```

Just in case, here is a [Parsley JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tnevy0f/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could simply use `data-parsley-type="email"` instead of `pattern`. This uses Parsley's builtin (and more accurate) regex for email.